# Why does ExtractIsoYear annotation not filter correctly?

Tags: django, django-queryset

In

- Django 2.2.18,
- Python 3.6,
- and PostGreSQL 12 (Version 2.4.2 (107)),

if I create an annotation that extracts the IsoYear, I can't filter on it correctly. Why?

```
import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractIsoYear

class Meal(models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)    

Meal(time=datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 31)).save()
Meal(time=datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1)).save()
Meal(time=datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 2)).save()
query = Meal.objects.all().annotate(
    isoyear=ExtractIsoYear('time')
)
print(query[0].isoyear)
# 2020
print(query[1].isoyear)
# 2020
print(query[2].isoyear)
# 2020
print(query.filter(isoyear=2020).count())
# 2
print(Meal.objects.filter(time__isoyear=2020).count())
# 2
```

My expectations is that, if the annotation for isoyear is `2020`, and I filter for the `isoyear=2020`, all three results should be returned. Was this a bug in Django 2?

In addition, filtering on iso_year is broken.

If I'm not allowed to filter on iso_year, it should throw an throw an exception, not give me the wrong answer...

Comment: Your question instead should be why all of those 3 prints are giving you 2020 since you had infact saved the first instance with the year as 2019.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat `isoyear` returns the year connected to the week, not the year from the date itself. More on that can be found https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date

Comment: @OwenBrown you are importing `ExtractIsoYear`, but using `ExtractYear` in the annotate. Are you sure you're using the same function in your code both when querying and when extracting the isoyear?

Comment: @GwynBleiD You're right, that was a typo. But using ExtractIsoYear gives the same result.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in Django ([#32573](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/32573)), that is already fixed and the fix should be released in the next update. I'm not sure if this fix will land in Django 2.2 (Theoretically it should as the support period for Django 2.2 is ending in April 2022, but that's for the extended LTS support, not sure which bugfixes qualify).

To get around this issue, you can change your queryset slightly:

```
query = Meal.objects.all().annotate(
    isoyear=Extract('time', lookup_name='iso_year')
)
```

From tests I've performed it looks like Django is not applying the (incorrect) optimization if you use the raw `Extract` annotation and specify the value to be extracted manually. But as I've performed only some basic testing on very simple querysets, this is not a guarantee and the optimization may kick in for some more complex queries regardless of the method of executing this lookup. Bear that in mind.

The only reliable way to fix that issue is to update Django in your project to the one with a fix applied as soon as it's released. You can track Django announcements blog to see when it happens.

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad this is corrected in later versions.